# Popup window on youtube - how to close with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Could you please help me with one issue?  I  have got a problem with Selenium and popup windows with agreements on youtube.
When first window is jumped - Selenium close this  window, but if I want to close second window/frame, selenium doesn't work. Could you please help?
The part of code attached below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from time import sleep
class YoutubeSearcher:
    def __init__(self, search):
        self.search = search
    def open_url(self) -> None:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/ytd-app/ytd-popup-container/paper-dialog/yt-upsell-dialog-renderer/div/div[3]/div[1]/yt-button-renderer/a/paper-button/yt-formatted-string'))).click()
        except:
            print("no alert to accept")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form'))).click()
        search = driver.find_element_by_id("search")
        search.clear()
        search.send_keys(self.search)
        submit_button = driver.find_element_by_id("search-icon-legacy")
        submit_button.click()
```

Comment: Which _second window/frame_ are you trying to interact with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you have share these are my observations :

First popup.

```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/ytd-app/ytd-popup-container/paper-dialog/yt-upsell-dialog-renderer/div/div[3]/div[1]/yt-button-renderer/a/paper-button/yt-formatted-string'))).click()
```

Second popup.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form'))).click()
```

Suggestion :

1. Check the xpath once if they are correct or are there multiple locators which are being returned.
2. Add apprropriate waits : like isVisible,clickable for both the locator popup.
3. Using basic if else you can make the conditions work (no specific need of try except).
4. After one popup is closed check if the next popup is visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that finally works. A switching frame is needed for the second pop up. It's lame, I know but it works.

Hope it helps. Good luck.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
                                            '/html/body/ytd-app/ytd-popup-container/paper-dialog/yt-upsell-dialog-renderer/div/div[3]/div[1]/yt-button-renderer/a/paper-button/yt-formatted-string'))).click()
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/c-wiz/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/span/span"))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It works, I find a similar solution!